# SharedPreferences doesn't save values on release mode Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I've just changed my projects to release mode and its suddenly make my SharedPreferences doesn't work as it works before the change. The value is always return as a 'null' even I save it as 1.

This is how I save the data

```
_storeOnBoardInfo() async {
int isViewed = 1;
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setInt('onBoard', isViewed);
}
```

and this is how a load the data

```
void main() async {

SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.white, statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark));
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  isViewed = prefs.getInt('onBoard');

  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
  runApp(const MyApp());

  FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
}
```

I tried some solutions but it doesn't work for me. Is there any other way to make solve this problem?

Comment: where did you call this `_storeOnBoardInfo()` ?

Comment: I think when you install this app for the first time, it hasn't saved "onBoard" shared preferences. You should check null such as this: `isViewed = prefs.getInt('onBoard') ?? -1;`

Comment: I called in on a button when it pressed it will be do that function.